# How do I bypass fan on my Inspiron 1501 mobo

Tags: fan

My Laptop is always running on the lowest fan speed for some obscure reason, I've download speedfan but i't can't control fan speed for unknown reason. I know that it can go into high speed because it does so just before window login screen.

I seriously need help, i'm runnin 75-80 celsius and i'm hitting the safe shutdown when I play games.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround.  Ensure that the laptop isnt sitting on something soft, like a bed or couch cushion.  This will prevent proper cooling.

Addidionally, you could purchase a laptop cooling stand like this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F5L001-Laptop-Cooling-Stand/dp/B000NWIOM6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NWIOM6)

THey are inexpensive and work well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fiddled with them, but fan control apps [like this one](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) seem fairly popular (apparently XP installed on a macbook commonly runs hotter than OS X, who knew?).

You may also wish to look into a BIOS update or settings to adjust the temperature/fan thresholds for your system.